# Can I get a breakdown of memory use?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

Can I get a better breakdown of memory use from within my app than GC.GetTotalMemory?  For example per-assembly or per-module?  Does that even make sense?

Comment: Just out of interest - why do you need this info within your application dynamically? Why not use good memory profiler to check for memory usage per module/class etc?

Comment: I've been asked to include this information in the application so non-techical testers can report on memory use.

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy to let your users use a 3rd party app, [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from SysInternals is pretty powerful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the performance counters from the System.Diagnostics namespace. See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f9bkxzf.aspx

Comment: Could you go into a little more detail?